# Issue setting environmental variable in tmux and screen

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, gnu-screen, path, python3

Whenever I use Tensorflow (a python library) from within a tmux or screen session, I have to manually change the environmental variables.  Specifically, I have to type `export PATH blah blah blah` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH blah blah blah`.  Normally (outside of tmux and screen) I don't need to do this, because my .bashrc contains *exactly these lines*.

The weird part is that for some reason, running `source ~/.bashrc` from with tmux or screen DOES NOT update the path variables.  I have also tried adding `source ~/.bashrc` to my `.profile`. So, my question is, what do I need to do in order for tmux and screen to automatically run my two export lines?

EDIT: After running `set -x; source ~/.bashrc`, the end of the printout reads:

```
    ++ export 'PATH=/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}'
++ PATH='/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}'
++ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib
++ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib
++ bind TAB:menu-complete
++ export 'PATH=/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}'
++ PATH='/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}'
++ export 'PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}}'
++ PATH='/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/home/ajherman/bin:/home/ajherman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin}}}}'
++ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib
++ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib:/home/ajherman/arrayfire-3/lib
```

Comment: What shell are you running in `tmux` and `screen`?

Comment: That is indeed strange. Run `set -x; source ~/.bashrc ; set +x`.

Comment: also check env in and out of TMUX, also your .bashrc likely has some conditionals so make sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is actually run

Comment: @Ari I approved your edit but you really should merge your two accounts: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: The most interesting parts are probably going to relate to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...

Comment: @RalfFriedl I added to my post the relevant part from running "set -x; source ~/.bashrc".

Comment: You seem to have junk (`}}`) at the end of your `PATH` variable value.

Comment: You have multiple copies of `/home/ajherman/anaconda3/bin`. That is not a problem, just unnecessary. Are the values displayed active after the source command?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I was confusing bash.bashrc with .bashrc, and had put the export lines in bash.bashrc.  However, after adding them to .bashrc and running source again, the problem still persists.  However, the printout from source is slightly different, so I've edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: You might be able to put the commands in ~/.screenrc

Comment: @user103944 The file didn't exist, so I created it and added the export lines.  No luck.  I also tried running "source ~/.screenrc" while in a screen session, but that did not work either.

Comment: @user103944 The tmux manual doesn't mention `~/.screenrc`.

Comment: @AriHerman After running `source .bashrc`, are the environment variables as you want them or not? If not, create a file `.myenv` (or whatever name) and read it with `source .myenv`.